# OpenShift rhc setup using multiple accounts

Tags: ssh, installation, openshift, ssh-keys, openshift-client-tools

I have two accounts on Openshift platform. How can I setup my computer so that I can manage both of them with `rhc`? I cannot find any relevant option in the command line arguments.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

The `rhc` command-line tools come with the global option `-l, --rhlogin LOGIN`. You have two options:

1. Use the `-l` flag with every command to specify the login name:

   ```
   rhc app create <appname> <cartridge> [-l <login1/login2>]
   ```
2. Run `rhc setup -l LOGIN` between the sessions. Once done managing apps from one account you can end the session for it by running `rhc account logout`.

   ```
   rhc setup -l <login1> # First account's login
   rhc app create <appname> <cartridge>
   rhc logout
   rhc setup -l <login2> # Second account's login
   rhc app create <appname> <cartridge>
   rhc logout
   ```

When you can `rhc setup` command, the username information gets stored in `.openshift/express.conf` file; hence the need to run it again when you want to switch the account.

Comment: when you say ***`<login>`***, what exactly does it mean??... username?? OR password??... I think it would be nicer to clearly let us know that you mean ***`<openshift-username>`***

Comment: But then how do you switch accounts? I can't find anything in the rhc help that indicates how to login once logged-out

Answer (score 12):

The command line also supports `--conf` - where you pass a file.  You can always alias the command via a shell script.

Answer (score 7):

Quite old question, but I use yet another solution which seems to be more comfortable (at least for me) - the environment variable `OPENSHIFT_CONFIG`.

The `OPENSHIFT_CONFIG` environment variable [can be used](https://lists.openshift.redhat.com/openshift-archives/dev/2013-May/msg00024.html) to override the OpenShift configuration name (by default "express"). When set the operations performed with rhc refers to `~/.openshift/${OPENSHIFT_CONFIG}.conf` (instead of `~/.openshift/express.conf`).

To switch to the another OpenShift account the following could be used (Bash):

```
export OPENSHIFT_CONFIG=thenewone 
rhc apps    //apps on the new account

...
unset OPENSHIFT_CONFIG
rhc apps    //apps on the default account
```

Verified with rhc 1.37.1, but should work with any version released after May 2013.

Answer (score 2):

When you run the `rhc setup` command for the first time, the `~/.openshift/express.conf` file is created, containing the settings for your initial server configuration. When you add another server, or run the `rhc setup` command again with the `--server` option, the `~/.openshift/servers.yml` file is created, containing the settings for each server. You can edit this file to make any changes to the server configuration, and this takes precedence over the initial `~/.openshift/express.conf` file.

```
rhc server use server.name.example.co
rhc server use Server_Nickname
```

More information [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/OpenShift_Online/2.0/html/User_Guide/chap-Multiple_OpenShift_Servers.html)

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, run these commands like and respond I did (denoted by `<` and `>`):

```
rhc setup -l login@domain.mail.com
```

```
Enter the server hostname: <openshift.redhat.com>
Password: <**********><Press Enter>
Generate a token now? (yes|no) y<Press Enter>
Generating an authorization token for this client ... lasts about 1 month
Saving configuration to C:\Users\UserName\.openshift\express.conf ... done
```

Your private SSH key file should be set as readable only to yourself. To make this change, run:

```
chmod 600 C:\Users\<Your Username>\.ssh\id_rsa
```

Your client tools are now configured.

Then you can use console commands for a long time with generated token for your OpenShift login.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure multiple accounts using the `server add` command and then you can provide the server nickname in all subsequent commands using `--server` option. For example:

```
rhc server add -l <first_account> --nickname srv1 <first-server>
rhc server add -l <second_account> --nickname srv2 <second-server>
```

You may add options like `-p, --use-authorized-tokens` to suppress the prompts for password and token-generation. Also `--insecured` if required

```
rhc server use srv1
rhc server use srv2
```

Commands above perform some sort of initialization. Once two steps above are done you are ready to use your multiple accounts.

Now in your `rhc` commands you need to specify which server should be used. For example:

```
rhc app-show -n <domain> <app> --server srv1
```

Command above will show details of app in `srv1`. For `srv2` you can run

```
rhc app-show -n <domain> <app> --server srv2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `rhc setup -l <login>`. Here `login` is your registered OpenShift account's `email address`.